# How to execute JS Code when Outlook is started with Web Add Ins?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I want to make a async request to my server every time a user of my plugin starts outlook (or at least before they open an email).

I have a web Add In with a function file. This file is called whenever a user press a button for this addin. The function file is only loaded after a button (of my plugin) press.

Comment: That's unclear for me why don't you want to make this request as your web add-in is initialized.

Comment: As I looked at the network tab: the function file is loaded after I click the first button of my plugin. Is there another option to execute code on load?

Comment: Outlook JS add-ins are tight to mail item and loaded by user action (button click) or automatically when add-in implements "pinnable" interface. This still has to be initiated by user first time add-in loads. There is no option to load the add-in on Outlook start.

Comment: It could be much difference between starting outlook and opening an email. The former is one-time thing, while the later happens every time when an email is opened. In what scenario, you need this feature? Also, when you say "open an email", does it mean opening an existing email or composing a new mail?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The Plugin is only used by my company. It works good on writing mails, but it should update the personal IP on a server when outlook starts. My current idea is to use a VSTO Add In for this. Or trigger it before reading every message (that would be a bit much)

Comment: Currently the feature, run an add-in on Outlook load, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with WebAddIns as the Outlook Add-Ins Teams said in the comments under the question.

One solution is to create a VSTO AddIn and make the request there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// This function is called when Office.js is ready to start your Add-in
Office.initialize = function ()
{
   $(document).ready(function () 
   {
      //call your function here
```

Comment: Thank you Victor for your Answer. This is only triggered after the file is loaded. And the file is only loaded, after a user clicks a button in the plugin.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Are you saying that after clicking on the icon of your add-in your code does not run? As far as I know Office.initialize procedure executes after starting the add-in.

Comment: Sry for the missunderstanding. My addin code (function.js) is only loaded (over network) when i click a button of this plugin (as i introduced in the manifest). the code you posted is not loaded when office is started.

Comment: If you interested only in add-in for Outlook (not for OWA) then create a COM add-in (VSTO or not - it doesn't matter).